# What path do I need to give to 'dd' when creating a bootable USB stick on Mac OS?

Tags: macosx, system-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu desktop and trying to create a bootable USB stick on Mac OS following [the guide on ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx). However, I'm stuck at the following step:

> Execute `sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m` (replace `/path/to/downloaded.img` with the path where the image file is located; for example, `./ubuntu.imgor ./ubuntu.dmg`

What is the path where the image file is located? I can't figure it up. Any support would be great appreciated.

Comment: Disk images are dmg/iso/etc... files. You want to input the absolute path of the image. If it's on you desktop, that would be `~/Desktop/ubuntu.iso`

Comment: I believe this question is on topic: it is about installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Just an FYI. Some older macbooks won't boot from USB.

Answer (score 2):

The guide contains a useful tip:

> **Tip:** Drag and drop a file from Finder to Terminal to 'paste' the full path without risking typing errors.

Here is what I would do:

1. write `sudo dd if=` (without pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>);
2. drag and drop the `.img` file to the terminal;
3. type a space, write `of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (remember to replace `N` with the correct number).

Comment: It worked for me thanks. One more thing, now flash drive is bootable by above steps can I install Ubuntu on any computer ? or only on Mac machines (Apple) ?

Comment: @Maulik: any computer

Answer (score 0):

1- Hi, you wrote "what this means: Execute sudo... " sudo is "Super User DO" more or less mind you take the privileges of an administrator of (your) equipment, so you can install the software.

2-   /path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN  is the path of image of ubuntu, mind then physical (usb key, cd rom reader) who contains the ISO (image of software self install for your computer)

3- I suppose you use the terminal console for make that steps, terminal console is an utility used for make scripts on operative system, is black screen and you can find like LXTerminal at Accesories on the start button (like win analogy).
Hope help you - sorry is not very clear, try and try again :)

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems creating a working usb-stick, so I just used Unetbootin, which makes creating a bootable usb-stick a breeze! (even though you can, you don't have to download an image yourself, since the program can do that for you!)
Select your designated distribution from the dropdown, or select an image from your local hdd, select the usb-stick (restart the program if it is not showing), and you are good to go!

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/